# how to get rid of readings when exported to excel

Tags: php, laravel

view before export
[image]

i want to remove read = export as i marked below. This export reading is found from the export button reading
[image]

my code in my view

```
    @foreach ($payroll_cutoff as $key => $cutoff)
         @php
               $start = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($cutoff->periode_start)->format('d M Y');
               $end = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($cutoff->periode_end)->format('d M Y');
               $count_employee = App\Models\PayrollCutoffEmployee::where('payroll_id', $cutoff->id)->get();
         @endphp

               <table class="table group-payroll table mb-0 table-bordered"  data-group_id="" data-payroll_id="{{$cutoff}}" data-period="{{ $start . ' - ' . $end }}" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-radius: 4px; overflow: hidden"  data-cols-width="5,30">
                    <thead class="head-component">
                          <tr>
                              <th colspan="7"> <i class="" style="display: none"></i></th>
                          </tr>
                    </thead>
                          <tbody class="body-component">
                              <tr>
                                  <td style="width: 100%" colspan="7">
                                       <span>{{ $x++ }}.</span>                                                               
                                                        
                                          <b strong class="ms-4">Periode: </strong></b><span>{{$start . ' - ' . $end }}</span>
                                          <b strong class="ms-6"></b> <span>{{ $count_employee->count() }} Orang </span>
                                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm mb-2 checkall me-5 show-emp  ms-6" style="background-color: #edf2f9; border-radius: 0%; border: 1px solid #dfe1e4;"><i class="export">=</i></a>                                                    
                                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn btn-success mr-1 float-end export" data-num="{{$key}}" onclick="exportReportToExcel({{$key}})">Export</a>
                                                         
                                    </td>
                              </tr>
                               <tr class="employee" style="display:none">
                                   <td style="font-weight: bold">Nama</td>
                                   <td style="font-weight: bold">Jabatan</td>
                                   <td style="font-weight: bold">GajiPokok</td>
                                   <td style="font-weight: bold">Lembur</td>
                                   <td style="font-weight: bold">Tunjangan</td>
                                   <td style="font-weight: bold">Total</td>
                               
                                               @foreach ($count_employee as $employee)
                                                        @php
                                                            $emp = App\Models\Employee::where('id', $employee->employee_id)->first();
                                                            $emp_company = App\Models\EmployeeInCompany::where('employee_id', $employee->employee_id)->first();
                                                        @endphp
                                                  
                                                        <tr class="employee" style="display:none">
                                                            <td>{{$emp->name}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$emp_company->position}}</td> 
                                                            <td>{{$basic_salary}}</td>                   
                                                            <td>{{$employee->overtime_total}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$employee->tunjangan}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$employee->total_salary}}</td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                    @endforeach
                                          
                                                    
                                                    <tr class="employee" style="display:none">
                                                        <td>Grand Total</td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td>{{$gaji}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{$lembur}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{$tunjang}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{$total}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>                                                                                                                  
   @endforeach
```

this is the javascript i use to export excel

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"></script>
    <script>
        function exportReportToExcel(key) {
            let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
            TableToExcel.convert(table[key], {
                name: `Report.xlsx`,
                sheet: {
                    name: 'Sheet 1'
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

I want them before exporting them to still show up but after exporting to excel they don't show up anymore.
I want to get rid of those = export reads because they are in the $key array so the reads still come along. how to solve my problem? please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question that you want to remove `=export`from your excel sheet. Try to hide `<a>` tag having class `export` before **convert** to excel. Or add some unique class to both these element to avoid any error.

```
    <script>
        function exportReportToExcel(key) {
              // hide export class tags
              var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('export')
              for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                   elements[i].style.display = 'none';
              }

            let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
            TableToExcel.convert(table[key], {
                name: `Report.xlsx`,
                sheet: {
                    name: 'Sheet 1'
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I understand what that means, but if I remove it, it will show my view before exporting. please check the updated image above.

Comment: I want them before exporting them to still show up but after exporting to excel they don't show up anymore.

Comment: I have updated answer, please check.

Comment: in excel there is still a reading = export but after exporting the new display it disappears like this ->https://imgbox.com/0YTwxYGc

Comment: image not opening

Comment: how about this -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FLpR3KAPJ9_dXhMPAJW3TW8EqFpumiNK/view

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Laravel maatweb for exporting the data? you can specify all data to be displayed in the excel document.